# PHP Curl not setting body param or content type

Tags: php, rest

I am currently trying to request a Graph token from Microsofts Grapgh Rest Api, I have it working with postman just fine, however when I try to send the same request via php curl I get

```
AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.
```

Upon receiving this error I checked the curl request before sending it, showing me that neither the body is getting set nor the Content type, as I am setting it to x-www-form but it stays as 'application/json.

Maybe someone knows what is up and can help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <?php
      $data = array('grant_type' => 'client_credentials', 'client_secret' => '****', 'client_id' => '****');
      $postdata = json_encode($data);

      $ch = curl_init();

      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/7390211a-8059-450c-ab26-2f8adac42536/oauth2/token?resource=https://graph.microsoft.com' );
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);

      $result = curl_exec($ch);
    ?>
    </head>
    <body>
      <?php echo $result ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Print_r of the on curl_getinfo($ch) results in this:

```
Array ( [url] => https://login.microsoftonline.com/7390211a-8059-450c-ab26-2f8adac42536/oauth2/token?resource=https://graph.microsoft.com [content_type] => application/json; charset=utf-8 [http_code] => 400 [header_size] => 686 [request_size] => 360 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.187 [namelookup_time] => 0.015 [connect_time] => 0.046 [pretransfer_time] => 0.14 [size_upload] => 139 [size_download] => 503 [speed_download] => 2689 [speed_upload] => 743 [download_content_length] => 503 [upload_content_length] => 139 [starttransfer_time] => 0.187 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => 40.126.1.166 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 443 [local_ip] => 192.168.15.231 [local_port] => 61831 )
```

Comment: Remove the ``json_encode($data)`` and just pass the ``$data``

Comment: @OMiShah Sadly that does not change the outcome at all

Comment: can I see the documentation you're following so that I can see what kind of data the api is requesting?

Comment: http://codematters.tech/getting-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-using-oauth-rest-api/ This is the guide I am following, like I said the postman part is working perfectly for me. The entire Microsoft Graph docs can be found here : https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/. Curl is not part of the tutorial, I am using the tutorial to understand the request structures and workflows

Answer (score 0):

Well I ended up going with a php snippet I found online that works like a charm for me.

```
$data = array('grant_type' => 'client_credentials', 'client_secret' => '****', 'client_id' => '****');
$url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/****/oauth2/token?scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadWrite.All';

          $options = array(
            'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
          )
        );
        $context  = stream_context_create($options);
        $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        if ($result === FALSE) { echo 'error'; }
```